# Decentraland total supply is difference in Ethereum and polygon?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, ethereum, polygon

I learning about blockchain and look in mana token Decentraland. I compared total supply in etherscan and polygonscan but there are difference why?

The Total Supply coinmarketcap: 2,193,554,627 `https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/decentraland/`

The Max Total Supply: etherscan: 2,193,554,627 `https://etherscan.io/token/0x0f5d2fb29fb7d3cfee444a200298f468908cc942`

The Total Supply polygonscan: 3,881,772 `https://polygonscan.com/token/0xa1c57f48f0deb89f569dfbe6e2b7f46d33606fd4`

any one can answer for it pleas.

I know some tokens use polygon or binance chain beside ethereum to add more scalable and less fee? if that true

Answer (score 0):

> but there are difference why?

One of the numbers is wrong.

> add more scalable and less fee? if that true

yes

Comment: you can see in this chain is difference: https://blockscout.com/xdai/mainnet/token/0x7838796B6802B18D7Ef58fc8B757705D6c9d12b3/token-transfers[link] . The total supply is 5,771.255 MANA
why

Comment: This website is not a support desk for CoinmarketCap, which is Binance owned company. Please write a question for their support why they are displaying wrong data.

Comment: The best way search in source origin. I do same search in sand token in etherscan Total Supply: 3,000,000,000 SAND. AND in polygonscan Total Supply: 135,195,839.717667 SAND. why This change and what is the true data. I think there are some secret about it

Comment: Maybe I find the answer in this page: https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/how-to-use-the-polygon-bridge[link] .  When bridging tokens across the Polygon Bridge, there won't be any changes to the circulating supply of the token. Tokens that leave the Ethereum network are locked, and the same number of tokens will be minted on the Polygon network as pegged tokens on a 1:1 basis. When bridging the tokens back to Ethereum, the pegged tokens on Polygon will be burned, and those on Ethereum will be unlocked during the process. I'm beginner in blockchain you can read it and give me more vision.